# Jenkins after nginx always caches last page

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins is configured according to the [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Hudson+behind+Nginx).

The problem is: first modifying a job then opening it to modify the next time, it is always showing the unmodified version.

Comment: does the config file on disk update?

Comment: @thekbb Yes, the config file is updated. Because when refresh the page again, it will show the modified content.